# Follow the signings?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, signage

I saw a road sign today saying:  "Follow the alt route *signings*."   It struck me odd.  I would expect: "Follow the alt route *signs*."

*Signings* is obviously a legitimate word, but it's usually used when there's an *act* of signing involved, like with book signings or hearing-impaired signing.   I suppose one might consider a road sign to be an "act of signing/signaling" but it seems like a stretch.

Is this a common use of the word I've just missed out on?  Construction jargon?   Or just a construction worker's peculiar choice?

Comment: Where, exactly, did you see this?

Comment: @tchrist - Driving on a highway that was under construction.  The full text was something along the lines of "Delays ahead.  Follow alt route signings", presumably suggesting to take the faster alternate route to avoid the delays.

Comment: That wasn’t what I was looking for.  I was looking for the geographical location, not the situational one.

Comment: @tchrist - Oh, sorry :)  Western Pennsylvania.

Comment: In the UK (and probably the US too), the normal word would indeed be **signs**. But the road-signs being referred to are probably somewhat different to "standard" signs (they're for an *alternative* route, after all). Perhaps the sign-writer used a different word to reflect that difference. To be honest, **signings** here looks really odd to me, but in the UK I wouldn't think there was anything at all odd if they'd written **signage** - which I would take to mean "non-standard/temporary road-signs" in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not even that in the UK: "Diversion Follow ◙" and just the symbol on subsequent signs. The OP's is probably a one-off and maybe the sign-maker got the spacing wrong: found that "sign" was in the wrong place and filled in with "ing" and then a final "s". Or, just an odd choice. This is almost Too Localised.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - It sounds like you're probably right that it's a one-off.  My question was trying to find out if that was the case.  Is asking if something is localized itself Too Localized? :)

Comment: @Lynn ('Is asking if something is localized itself Too Localized?') No, but if the community checks that the question is Too Localized, then the question have to be closed at all!

Comment: I think [_signage_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=signage&ls=a) would have been a better word than [_signings_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=signing&ls=a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google tells me that, *in the UK*, this might be a peculiarity that has come about thanks to health and safety regulations for the construction industry which are particular about ["Signing, Lighting and Guarding (SLG) guidelines"](http://www.hsa.ie/eng/Your_Industry/Construction/Construction_FAQ%27s/Roadworks.html):

> What are the main provisions of the amended Regulation 97?
>
> (a) There must be on site, at all times when the works are in progress and workers are on site, at least one person who has been issued with a valid construction skills registration card relating to  either “health and safety at roadworks”  or “**signing, lighting and guarding**”. Furthermore the works must be supervised by a competent person who has been issued with a valid construction skills registration card relating to **signing, lighting and guarding** on roads.

In other words, as the OP suspected, this is very likely jargon particular to the construction industry. One explanation for the use of *signings* could be due to their temporary nature (during construction). I couldn't make out if these regulations also involved a person manually directing traffic (often seen in some countries), a requirement which would make the use of *signing* more obvious.

I also have no idea if the occurrence in the US is a one-off or not. But I did come across [one reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=TndRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22road%20signings%22&dq=%22road%20signings%22&source=bl&ots=_yLlRi63sJ&sig=IzcIDp7BJj1sClFf-nm96sWGPL8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WUYtUPH5L4iHrAfonoGABw&redir_esc=y) which might suggest that it is possible.